# How to pass a variable from shell script to sql file

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, shell

I am having a shell file named test.sh which is invoking other sql file 'table.sql'. 'table.sql' file will create some tables, but I want to create the tables in a particular schema 'bird'.

content of sql file.

```
create schema bird; --bird should not be hard coded it should be in variable
set search_path to 'bird';
create table bird.sparrow(id int, name varchar2(20));
```

content of shell file.

```
dbname=$1
cnport=$2
schemaname=$3
filename=$4

gsql -d ${dbname} -p ${cnport} -f ${filenam} #[how to give schema name here so that it can be used in table.sql without hardcoding]
```

I will execute my shell file like this

```
sh test.sh db1 9999 bird table.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easier doing it in shell, eg:

```
dbname=$1
cnport=$2
schemaname=$3
filename=$4

gsql -d ${dbname} -p ${cnport} <<EOF
create schema $3; --bird should not be hard coded it should be in variable
set search_path to '$3';
create table bird.sparrow(id int, name varchar2(20));
EOF
```

otherwise use psql variables